# accessing a custom library in Zend with proper naming conventions

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-loader

Him 
Can anyone tell me how can I access the library in ZEND framework and what is the proper naming convention for libraries in ZEND. I have the following struture

---

```
--application
--docs
--library
    --myLibrary.php (class name is also same)
--public
```

How can I access this library in my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your library is really a single class called `myLibrary` stored in `library/myLibrary.php`, then you should be able to add the following to your `application/configs/applicatiom.ini` file:

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "myLibrary"
```

Then you should be able to instantiate a `myLibrary` object using:

```
$lib = new myLibrary();
```

Comment: I did as u said. but I am getting the following error  Failed opening 'Tt\Soap\Helper.php' for inclusion (include_path='E:\zend CE\Apache2\htdocs\store-app\application/library;E:\zend CE\Apache2\htdocs\store-app\library;.;E:\zend CE\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library') in E:\zend CE\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Loader.php on line 146

Comment: Does the file `Tt/Soap/Helper.php` reside on your `include_path`?

Comment: my library name is Tt_Soap_Helper. and yes I assume that it resides on include path. coz the folder path in error is right.

Comment: please help me out.. I am stuck here

Comment: @FaizanAli: Seems we are misunderstanding each other re: the terms 'library name' and 'class name'. `Tt_Soap_Helper` is a 'class name'. It resides in the `Tt` pseudo-namespace, so it is pretty common to refer to `Tt` as a 'library'. If the `Tt` folder resides in your `library` folder, then you should only need to add another `autoloadernamespaces` entry to your `application/configs/application.ini` file: `autoloadernamspaces[] = "Tt_"`

Comment: lets just say .. that I have a class with a name Tt_Soap_Helper. it contains custom soap helper function I have written. Where should I place this file according to ZEND standards ? and how do I autoload this file so that I do not have to include it to use it

Comment: @FaizanAli: See my answer above. Place the file containing the class `Tt_Soap_Helper` in `library/Tt/Soap/Helper.php`. Then in `application/configs/application.ini`, add a line: `autoloadernamespaces[] = "Tt_"` (my previous comment had a typo). Then any call like `$helper = new Tt_Soap_Helper();` will invoke the autoloader.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to create your own library directory:

```
library
    My
        Library.php
    Zend
```

Add this to ypur index.php:

```
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->registerNamespace('My_');
```

And use this class:

```
$obj = new My_Library();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if your `library` folder is on the include path then you can use `myLibrary` directly.

Comment: it is on the include path. but I am constantly getting that anoying error that library is not present there